# Unresolved dependencies: com.typesafe.play (Play Java)

Tags: playframework, sbt

I am receiving a similar error regarding typesafe.play. I have added scalaVersion := "2.11.7" to my build.sbt file and still seeing the same error.

**build.sbt**

```
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
  .dependsOn(celsus)
  .aggregate(celsus)

lazy val celsus = (project in file("libs/celsus"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.3.11"
)
```

**plugins.sbt**

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.4")
```

**Error received**

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:
...
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last root/:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output. [error] (celsus/:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-server_2.10;2.5.4: not found [error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.10;2.5.4: not found [error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-netty-server_2.10;2.5.4: not found [error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-logback_2.10;2.5.4: not found [error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.10;2.5.4: not found [error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-omnidoc_2.10;2.5.4: not found
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: I recommend you to use scala version 2.11.8. Also I don't think you need the line with `resolvers +=`. Also try to remove the `target` folder and try again.